# How to fix permission denied error when trying to run scala on OS X?

Tags: macos, scala

I put the extracted files into different places... tried usr/local, my home directory, etc. Even tried chmod 777 on the files. I keep getting Permission Denied when I try to run the interpreter. The /bin dir is definitely in my $PATH and I've restarted the Terminal. Ideas?

Update: somehow I fixed it by deleting everything, extracting Scala again, and putting a reference to my /Users/me/scala/ folder in .bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Repair Permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repair_permissions)?

Comment: Cool idea, but it didn't help.